# How to load a strongswan plugin at runtime

Tags: linux, plugins, centos6, strongswan

We've authored a plugin for **libcharon** that makes calls to our code. This is creating some unwanted coupling between our application and strongswan, since we're compiling strongswan with this plugin.

Let's call this plugin **MyPlugin**.
It is configured as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/strongswan/strongswan.d/charon/myplugin.conf
myplugin {

    # Whether to load the plugin. Can also be an integer to increase the
    # priority of this plugin.
    load = yes

    proxy
    {
        # Should send to proxy
          send_to_proxy = yes
    }
    log
    {
                # Should save to file
                  log_path = /var/log/myplugin.log
                  log_ips = yes
    }
}
```

We would like to reverse this dependency, by compiling this plugin as a part of our application, implementing strongswan interfaces.

The question is, does strongswan support this?
Can a plugin be deployed on a machine where strongswan is already running, and have strongswan load it and work with it? How?

We're running strongswan 5.1.5 on CentOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. However, there are some caveats:

- strongSwan does not provide any stable APIs. So this only works safely if you compile your plugin against the headers of the strongSwan version that's eventually loading the plugin.
- You will need `config.h` from the build you are compiling against (or of an equivalently configured build for the same platform). When compiling the plugin, you pass the path to it via `-include`.
- Loading the plugin via config snippet requires an appropriate `strongswan.conf` file (i.e. enable [modular plugin loading](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/PluginLoad) and include the config snippets in `strongswan.d` where you place a snippet for your plugin - [the default](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/StrongswanDirectory) should work fine).
- There might be licensing issues with third-party plugins, whether out-of-tree or not (strongSwan is licensed under the GPLv2, however, a commercial license is available).

You can find an example of an out-of-tree plugin [here](https://github.com/tobiasbrunner/strongswan-redirect-plugin).